# What does it mean if the status of manuscript changed directly from "editor assigned" to "reviews completed"?

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a manuscript to a journal a month ago but the status was changed to "reviews completed" after "editor assigned," with nothing in between. What does that mean?

Comment: It means, most likely, exactly what it says. What's your confusion with that statement?

Comment: To be concise, brace yourself to receive a rejection.

Comment: @Coder  Why? Depending on the field one month might be a pretty typical time for a normal review which might be positive or negative.

Comment: My money would be on a reject after a quick technical screening by the handling editor.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the reviewers have completed their work and submitted their reviews. The editor will now make a decision based on her judgment as well as the opinions of the reviewers, and you should expect to hear back from the journal shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but directly the status changed from editor assigned to reviews complete. Usually it must be changed to under review after editor assigned and then it changes to reviews completed.

Comment: @R.Behmanesh Is it possible you just didn't check it while it was under review?

Comment: No, I have been checking.